# Run Process Builder action Check based on nested conditions

Tags: process-builder, case, send-email

During Email to Case process, I built a process builder which runs on the email message objects and checks for multiple conditions before executing actions

> > Here's a scenario:
> >     (If it is incoming email and case status is closed)

```
[EmailMessage].Incoming = true &&
ISPICKVAL([EmailMessage].Parent.Status,"Closed")

Then Reopen the Case
```

Problem is that now when using standard Salesforce "Send EMail" action is used from contact or opportunity (email quote/pdf) - I get the following error:

```
Error element myDecision (FlowDecision).
The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Parent.Status because it hasn't been set or assigned.
```

> I believe this is because, even when sending email, it checks the process builder condition and does not find a case associated to the email message being sent and hence fails

```
Correct me If I am wrong
```

Now, I have to fix it and they way I have done it is that,

> I have taken a new condition at the top of process builder which checks if incoming email is False then update email message status as existing status which is essentially a dummy update.

Is there any other way I can achieve this without code.?

Please advise

Comment: why not have the PB check the value of EmailMessage.ParentId (1st three chars) to stop if not `500` ?

Comment: I can add any condition, but still it will check
 ISPICKVAL([EmailMessage].Parent.Status,"Closed")
condition and then fail.

Comment: I Want something like 
If Incoming Email is True -> Only then check next set of conditions > Else stop

Problem is I even tested nested IF but still it checks all conditions under Nested IF and again fails on finding the condition ISPICKVAL([EmailMessage].Parent.Status,"Closed")

Comment: have the first decision block STOP if `LEFT(TEXT(EmailMessage.ParentId),3) <> '500'` this will exclude all emailmessages not associated to a Case